# wordpress - create seo friendly lnks from my plugin

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm creating a Wordpress plugin with this address

```
//worpress/my-plugin/
```

and I'd like to pass (by GET) some variables in seo friendly form like

```
//worpress/my-plugin/first-var/second-var/
```

Is there any way to "create" and "get" these variables from my plugin without changing the .htaccess file (the permalink setting is already set in "Post name" mode) but just inserting some code in my plugin page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Rewrite api of wordpress:
below is a small example:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'add_rules'));
add_rewrite_rule('nameofurl/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?page_id=' . $post_ID . '&jsubscribe_id=$matches[1]', 'top');//if you need this for any specefic post.
/* OR */
 add_rewrite_tag('%action%', '([^/]+)');
 add_permastruct('action', 'url_prefix_like_plugin_name' . '/%action%');

 /*After adding permastruct do below work*/
 add_filter('template_redirect', 'function_name');
 /*Get you query value and do what you want*/
 function function_name(){
   $action=get_query_var('jaction');
   //put your login here
 }
```

and don't forget to flush_rewrite_rules();

for more information visit to below links:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct
```